# Lists to columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([CIK, period, data]), columns=['CIK','Period','Text'])
```

I have 3 lists which I want to be columns of my dataframe. Above code worked fine when my data was small. Now this gives me memory error. Am I missing something?
Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a dataframe by passing a `dict` to it.

```
i = ['CIK','Period','Text']
j = [CIK, period, data]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(i, j))
```

This is cheap as it doesn't result in creating copies of your data. The `dict` simply generates key-value pairs around the references (there's no need to create any data copies, only references are being moved around). Unfortunately, with your `column_stack` call, the arrays must be stacked into a *freshly allocated array* and a new result returned, which is wasteful.

Comment: That's really interesting, Coldspeed. Could you elaborate a little more on why that is?

Comment: @jlaur No problem, elaborated a bit on that.

Comment: New for me as well! +1